# What tools do I need to send data from my DB on a EC2 instance to my mobile application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I first started using the aws serverless technologies (RDS, Lambda, API gateway) and built a "serverless" mobile application. But now I want to learn using EC2.

Lets say I setup a Cassandra DB on my ec2 instance and make queries, how exactly do I send the queried data to the user? In serverless I would make a get request using an API gateway endpoint, triggering a lambda function that would query my RDS instance and send the data back. But I have no idea how I would do it using EC2. (Trying to create a realtime chat application using NoSQL)

Comment: If you actually have an EC2 server with a database on it, one way to do it would be to have a web-server (apache) using CGI (You call a web-page (cgi/script) that "does whatever" and returns "whatever" to the client (the cgi code does the magic - connects to the db, returns html, or whatever, etc). I've done all of my development using that technology (mostly Oracle, but would work with any database). I'm a bit of an old dog, so maybe there are other better ways since I've done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an API server on the EC2 instance which can run the code you use on lambda functions right now. I am assuming you use either Python or NodeJS on Lambda. The same code can be used on the EC2 instance with slight modifications.

Here is a tutorial on creating an API server using Express/NodeJS - https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9

This is a similar tutorial using flask/Python - https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

The API server functions pretty much like your lambda function. You specify the route and your lambda function code now goes inside the API server.